# How do you ensure that a commit is never deleted?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a purely speculative commit that didn't work.  I'd like to keep it, but I don't want to make a ref  (I don't want a branch or a tag named 'one-single-speculative-commit', and I certainly don't want 100s of them.)  I can make a branch name 'speculative', and put all the commits in it, but the commits are totally unrelated to each other so the linkage between a commit and its parent is absurd.  Essentially, I'd like to be able to list a bunch of sha1 ids for commits that will not be deleted by gc, but not need a ref for each one.  What's a good way to do that?  (I don't want to set gc.pruneExpire to a high value, because I do still want to prune things, just want to keep a specific set of commits that are otherwise unreferenced.)  In other words:

What is a good way to make a reference to a collection of totally unrelated commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I've decided to go with is relatively simple.

```
$ git update-ref refs/speculative/SHA1 SHA1
```

git-gc seems to respect the ref and not delete it.  The protected commits can be listed easily with:

```
$ git show-ref | grep refs/speculative
```

The only drawback I notice so far is that git fsck --lost-found HEAD reports that they are dangling.

Comment: Don't pass `HEAD` to `git fsck` - this will result in dangling commits if there is ANY commit outside of HEAD. You should instead just do `git fsck --unreachable`

Comment: +1: I was about to suggest this as an alternative to mipadi's answer. A couple notes: you should probably give the refs real names, not just the SHA1, so that you can tell them apart later. They're just like branches or tags, just outside of those namespaces - so name them descriptively, like you would any other ref. You can also list them with `git for-each-ref refs/speculative/*`, which gives you some nice formatting options.

Comment: I decided to use the sha1 as the name to ensure uniqueness and minimize the effort required to name them.  Telling them apart is easy enough by listing the first line of each commit message.

Answer (score 4):

I'd just tag the commit (using a lightweight tag). I know that's not the solution you really want, but it's the best one in my opinion. Tagged commits will never be expunged, and they won't show up when listing branches. They will when listing tags, but if you really don't want to see them, you could begin each tag with a common prefix, and then use a git alias to filter them out. Something like:

```
[alias]
    tags = !sh -c 'git tag | grep -v my_prefix'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `git stash`, which is essentially a different list connected to a ref called 'stash' that all the tools like `git show-branch` ignore.

Or you could use a branch for each in a fake remote, e.g. `refs/remotes/graveyard/an-experiment` which will not be included in `--branches` but is in `--all` so won't be pruned.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `git stash` as it would interfere with the normal use of `git stash` - ie, temporary storage of work-in-progress data

Comment: I played with stash for awhile, but it gets in the way of using the stash for stashing.  Fake remote is a good idea; but I'll still need a unique name for each, right?  I'd rather put the description in the commit message than the branch name.

Comment: You can put the description into the commit before placing them into the remote. If you want to add an additional 'envelope' commit for the overall branch description, use `git commit --allow-empty` to add an empty commit to the end .